# Byte stream in c++

Tags: c++

I have an application that receives groups of bytes of an arbitrary length on one thread (the input thread), and needs to process these bytes in chunks of 1024 on another thread (the processing thread). So I figured I would use some bytestream type that can be written to on the input thread, and be read from on the processing thread.

I used an `std::stringstream` for this and it works but has a memory leak.

Declaration:

```
std::stringstream _bytestream{};
int _bytestreamSize{0};
```

On the input thread:

```
_byteStream.write((char*) inputData, inputLength);
_bytestreamSize += inputLength;
```

On the processing thread:

```
// ... inside some processing loop ...
while (_bytestreamSize >= 1024) {
  _byteStream.read((char*) dataToProcess, 1024);
  _bytestreamSize -= 1024;
}
```

This works fine, but the string inside the `std::stringstream` just keeps growing. I tried with an `std::stringbuf` instead but ran into the same problem.

My questions:

- is `std::stringstream` or `std::stringbuf` a good type to use for this?
- If yes, how do I use it correctly? How do I free the memory of the bytes that have been read?
- If no, does there exist a standard type or approach which is more suited?

Remark: it's ok to assume that the processing thread can process the incoming bytes fast enough to not get into trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `std::stringstream` will never *actually* release its memory until you destroy it. This is a known issue with `std::stringstream`, in that you cannot reduce its internal buffer.

The workaround is too destroy the stringstream after each use, so instead of trying to reduce its size, simply create a new one for each input and send it through your pipeline. If you need to store the read data internally somewhere, have a second stringstream or similar which you write the output data too.

Comment: Tha'ts a pitty, it would be an elegant solution. The workaround makes things more difficult in  because I don't know the amount of input bytes. It could be less than or more than 1024. Also, I can't simply destroy the stringstream as long as it contains bytes that have not been read yet. In fact, I have no guarantee that it will ever get in a state where no bytes have to be read anymore (i.e. _bytestreamSize == 0).

Comment: Just have an external counter which keeps track of the bytes read, when you read from the stream the internal "cursor" is moved anyway so just keep reading until you get on EOF (like with a file). When I say destroy the strinstream I mean just let it go out of scope for example in your loop or at the end of your function